# What is the most convenient way to setup a bitmask to use against an int equal to 0xFFFF0000

Tags: c#, bitmask

For some reason C# does not want to implicitely use 0xFFFF0000 as a value as it is above int.MaxValue. What I would expect is that it could be casted somehow to be the corresponding negative value.

I have to do some bitwise operations and I would like to set an int as 0xFFFF0000 just for this purpose independently of the sign.

However this will not compile:

```
int leftmask = 0xFFFF0000;
```

The error is:

```
Error   1   Cannot implicitly convert type 'uint' to 'int'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) c:\....\Program.cs  127 28
```

Comment: Have you tried `uint leftmask = 0xFFFF0000;`

Comment: Yes but some reason it did not like operations with signed int afterwards which is also a bit weird.

Comment: Instruct the `enum` to use uint as its base storage type. I forget the exact syntax.

Comment: Yes unfortunately, this was for an interview on Codibility, and they give me signed ints. I had to submit anyway, no worries I did a `<< 16` but did not have time to test so I submitted another solution.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what was the question ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18299738/maximum-length-of-a-descending-path-in-a-tree-which-always-goes-leftright/25836118#25836118 , I put my C# solution although it is a Java tag, because the algorithm is still right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, as you said, that value won't "fit" to integer by default,

if you don't care about the semantics, you can just force it:

```
int leftmask = unchecked((int)0xFFFF0000);
```

Answer (score 3):

This will do the trick:

```
int leftmask = ~0xFFFF;
```

Comment: I voted up for your solution but accepted Erti-Chris solution as it seems slightly clearer for me, but yours is good also.